# Registering an App at Azure Active Directory to generate a Client Id

Tags: azure, dynamics-crm, azure-active-directory, dynamics-crm-online, dynamics-crm-webapi

I'm slightly confused on how to register an app in my Azure Active Directory. I'm running a Microsoft Dynamics CRM on-Demand app at `<myorg>.crm4.dynamics.com`. In order to run some simple blackbox tests I decided to write a small Java-based web client, by using [ADAL4J](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-java) and using the CRM Web api. From what I've understood I need to register my application in the AAD. Am I right to assume to register it as native? Since it is running merely some Request/Post-Requests locally? What do I need to configure for the redirect-uri in this use-case?

In a process of trial & error I registered an app with my resource-uri (`<myorg>.crm4.dynamics.com`) as the redirect-uri and granted the necessary permission to access the Dynamics CRM Api. To my surprise it worked and I was able to retrieve an access token using the respective client id. The reason why I am still asking the question here is because the configuration I took still felt wrong to me. It isn't my CRM-App at `<myorg>.crm4.dynamics.com` which I need to register but the Web Client which accesses the API with requests like `<myorg>.crm4.dynamics.com/api/data/v9.0/accounts`, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To consume Dynamics CRM webapi from Java based web client, you have to register the CRM app (not the Java app) in Azure AAD & Application Id (earlier called as Client Id) can be used to get the token for authentication.

[Walkthrough: Register a Dynamics 365 app with Azure Active Directory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-engagement/developer/walkthrough-register-dynamics-365-app-azure-active-directory)

> App registration in Azure Active Directory is typically done by ISVs who want to develop external client applications to read and write data in Customer Engagement. Registering an app in Azure Active Directory provides you with Application ID and Redirect URI values that ISVs can use in their client application's authentication code.